# TypeScript: concat arrays with different element-types

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

This is working.

```
let head = [["title", "value"], ["a", 1]];
let tail = [["b", 2], ["c", 3]];

let all = head.concat (tail);
```

The fine result is

```
[["title", "value"], ["a", 1], ["b", 2], ["c", 3]]
```

But what I need is this - and thats not working.

```
let head = [["title", "value"]];
let tail = [["a", 1], ["b", 2], ["c", 3]];

let all = head.concat (tail);
```

Error:

```
Argument of type '(string | number)[][]' is not assignable to parameter 
of type 'string[] | string[][]'. 
 Type '(string | number)[][]' is not assignable to type 'string[][]'. 
  Type '(string | number)[]' is not assignable to type 'string[]'. 
   Type 'string | number' is not assignable to type 'string'. 
    Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

It works if I make the numbers in tail to strings - what I can not do because of reasons.

So how can I make it work??

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can declare the type of `head` like this:

```
let head: [Array<string|number>] = [["title", "value"]];
```

This will remove the error and keep the type-safety in place.

Comment: To narrow further `let head: Array<[string, string|number]>`

Answer (score 14):

The recommended way to concat arrays these days is using es6 array spread. Type will be inferred correctly.

See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#spread_in_array_literals)

```
const all = [...head, ...tail];
```

Comment: Please explain your answer furtehr

Comment: Surely you know how this works, it was flagged in review queues.  :-)

Comment: Fyi, looking at some benchmarks, spread is slightly slower. Probably insignificant in 99% of cases but if you need high perf, take that into account.

Comment: Looking at some other benchmarks; Spread is quicker :)
https://jsbench.me/kvl9rixhob/1

I think spreads are much more optimized now than during the early days

Answer (score 3):

You can just do this: `[].concat(head, tail)`